# OpenERP Mobile Client page refresh issue

Tags: javascript, odoo

I have to do some customization work on OpenERP Mobile Client. The Problem is that it works on  #tag Url's like

```
http://localhost:8069/web_mobile/static/src/web_mobile.html#oe_menu or 
http://localhost:8069/web_mobile/static/src/web_mobile.html#oe_sec_menu_21
```

Problem is that one I am on any page and for any reason if i Refresh the contents never Loads again. it just gives me a blank page. If I copy the URL and Paste in a different Browser window then also nothing. I cant Find out whats the Problem In the Code or how it works. The Documentation of Mobile Client is too Poor. 
I am banging my head here from last one week I need Help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is no specific mobile console for R&D purpose. So its core issue from mobile client.But other alternative is use Back button click event for navigate the page which is shown on top of page instead of browser back button.

You can used Home button as well as Back button for refreshing purpose.

Comment: The Problem is that What if in the Third Stage of Form Filling the end user refresh the page ? He is a Normal user and in the loss of connectivity he will Refresh the page which must be acceptable but in OpenERP Mobile if the Page is refreshed then you will have to start from the Beginning i.E. The Login Page. Not Acceptable.

Comment: are you check & filling the data using mobile or web browser?